# nanoExpress Route Separate

Tags: javascript, express, nanoexpress

I want to separate route directory, but i can't and get below error.

```
rror [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './cjs' is not defined by "exports" in /mnt/.../projects/.../nanoexpress/node_modules/nanoexpress/package.json
```

app.js

```
const nanoexpress = require('nanoexpress');
var indexRouter     = require('./routes/index');
const app = nanoexpress();
const port = 3333;
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})
app.use('/testy',indexRouter)
app.listen(port)
```

routers/inde.js

```
const nanoexpress = require('nanoexpress/cjs');
const Route = require('nanoexpress/cjs/Route');
const app = nanoexpress();

const testRoute = new Route();
testRoute.get('/route', async () => 'hello');

module.exports.testRoute = testRoute;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. you need to register the route instance first.
Read more here: https://nanoexpress.js.org/routes/route

[image: Usage of Route Instance]

Comment: I did if you see my code, but it didn't work.

Comment: @PayamOmrani Order is important here i think. you must do: app.use("/testy", indexRouter) , right after creating "indexRouter" instance of route. It's there in documentation. please read it. Check this comment on the website:   "if you want Route to work properly, first initialize via app.use(routerInstance) then registrate your routes"

Comment: Thank you for responding ... but it didn't work.